# Batman Arkham Origins will not start (MSVCR100.dll was not found)

Tags: steam, batman-arkham-origins

I just downloaded Batman AO on steam but when I start it, it just says running for a second then it stops, syncs, and then nothing. Verified game cache, restarted computer, updated all my drivers, I've done a lot. I also tried running the game straight from the .exe from my steam folder but I'm met with this error message.

*The code execution cannot proceed because MSVCR100.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.*

I've had the problem of with 3 other games not being able to run, Depth, Geometry Dash, and Kingdom Rush. I tried reinstalling those and it didn't work. I don't want to reintall Batman AO since it's a much larger game and it didn't work for my other games. All my other games work just fine. Does anyone know a fix to this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to install the Microsoft Visual C redistributables.  It differs by game, but if you go to `Steam\steamapps\common\Batman Arkham Origins`, is there a folder named something like `_CommonRedist`?  If so, drill into that and install, just, everything.

Comment: Worse case scenario, you can download the Visual Studio 2010 Redistributable directly from Microsoft's website.  Unfortunately, just from the DLL name, you don't know if it is the initial release or one of the service packs.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft There is a folder named that, I'm sorry I'm not too familiar with this though, so what is it I exactly should do?

Comment: Go through each of the folders inside and run the installers